# Mysterious creeper-like explosions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play on my Hard difficulty survival world, part of the ceiling of my blacksmith's keeps missing blocks.

What's interesting is that it looks like a creeper explosion, but the fact that I never saw any creeper there, and that it only happened in that spot, made me think that the cause may be something else.

[image: Before...]

[image: and after.]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The wood is catching on fire and burning from the lava.

If there is an adjacent flammable block (e.g: wood above), lava can create fire in air blocks in this shape:

[image: 5*1*5 on top of 3*1*3]

You should be able to move your roof up one, make it out of non-flammable blocks, or put blocks such as torches in all the spots that fire could occur in order to block it.

Comment: Ah, yes, the famous Minecraft fire strikes again.

Comment: Making your ceiling higher or your floor lower would work too

Comment: So burning torches are fireproof? Minecraft logic.